# Xcode 6 storyboard unwin segue action is not defined

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

I have been using unwind segues in my project for a while without problem. I set them up the way it's supposed to be, and it's been working fine. Then suddenly today in Storyboard, I get this warning "The segue <> action is not defined". I checked my code and the unwind methods are still there in my view controller .m files. Nothing in my code has changed. I still have about 10 unwind segues defined in the .m files, but only 2 of them can be seen now in storyboard.

[image]

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Xcode 6.1.1
Objective-C

Comment: Hey, did you find any answers to this? I am having the same issue now. Also, I am not able to create new segues.

Comment: Hi @Sunil, I did not find an answer to this. I still have the issue. Maybe you can upvote the question to help?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!
I'm not sure what combinations of these things did the trick, if any, but here's what I did:
1. closed Xcode
2. deleted everything under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. deleted ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
4. rebooted the Mac
5. started Xcode
6. opened my project
7. control-dragging to Exit now works

Comment: I tried on my coworker's macbook, he's working on the same project files as me, and the issue is on his computer also.

For people's information, I did try to clean up the derived data, uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it, checking the project out of git to another folder, but none of these worked.

Comment: I tried your updated answer but it still doesn't work :( I'm on a new computer just pulled my project from git..

Comment: Did you try the steps after checking the project out of git ?  I think the key for me was deleting the cache, but I don't know for sure.  So, if you check the project out, then close Xcode and delete the com.apple.dt.Xcode, and then start Xcode and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I did clear the cache after I checked out the project. I actually did all the steps you listed after I checked out the project on the new computer. It seems that the issue is located somewhere else and not in the cache (in my case). I found a workaround to allow me to use the missing unwind segues tho.

Answer (score 0):

The error I got was "The segue action [unwindAction] is not defined"
This was resolved by removing the reference to the viewController.swift file in Xcode and adding it back.